# window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob is undefined in Office Add-in WebView Edge browser

Tags: office365, office-js, microsoft-edge, add-in, word-addins

As per the requirement of our application, we invoke in-house API to get .pdf base64 file string.

And this .pdf base64 string will be passed to code that allows an option to download file from Office Add-in to end-user, Edge WebView is now loading Office Add-in as our Windows and Office is updated to latest one.

Code snippet is as follows:

```
var pdfAsDataUri = "data:application/pdf;base64," + base64FileString;
if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
 // Create the Blob URL:
 var buffer = convertDataURIToBinary(pdfAsDataUri);
 var blob = new Blob([buffer], {
 type: 'application/pdf'
});
 window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "download.pdf");
} else {
 window.open(pdfAsDataUri);
}
```

In above code snippet `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` is undefined, hence we are unable to serve purpose of .pdf base64 file download option to end-user.

As `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` is `undefined`, else part is getting executed which throws `SEC7134` error with an exception as `Access is denied`.

And we are in blocker state for end-users who have updated their Windows and Office versions.

Also, this application was working fine, previous to updating Windows and Office versions, IE WebView was serving the purpose.

Please help with solution if anyone is facing same issue or found a solution.

Our Environment:

- Platform [PC desktop, Mac, iOS, Office Online]: PC Desktop
- Host [Excel, Word, PowerPoint, etc.]: Word
- Office version number: Office 365 16.0.11929.20586 64-bit version
- Operating System: Windows 10 1909 version

Comment: Which version of WebView version are you using? In your website, you could try to download the file from server side and use the Response class. Like [this sample](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-Download-PDF-file-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT userAgent of my Edge WebView is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; WebView/3.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18363`. And we have an AngularJS app which is loaded inside OfficeJS Word Add-in. Also we are getting .pdf base64 string by calling in-house API.

Comment: Try to use the [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) plugin.

Comment: Also I have logged issue on officejs GitHub official repo with demo website and word Add-in manifest xml to reproduce scenario along with artifacts gif file. For more details refer this link https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1006

Comment: No luck using download.js plugin, but Word Add-in crashes with this code. And when I referred plugin download() method it is internally having same code which I have posted in this question.